# Count WP_Query returns 0 in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to implement a custom pagination in Wordpress and I cannot get the number of posts to dynamically create the pagination element.

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type'         => 'product',
                'post_status '      => 'publish',
                'orderby'           => 'post_date',
                'order'             => 'date',
                'posts_per_page'    => $per_page,
                'offset'            => $start,
                'tax_query' => array( 
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => $suv_cates
                    )
                )

            )
        );

$count = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type'         => 'product',
                'post_status '      => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'tax_query' => array( 
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => $suv_cates
                    )
                )
            )


 );

 return $count->post_count;
```

The first query with the `$loop` returns the posts that I need. But when I return the `$count` or `$count->post_count`, it returns 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the first query. So add this code after first loop and query

```
wp_reset_postdata(); 
wp_reset_query();
```

Then let me know the result.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Posts per page is set to -1.

You could just count Loop?

Comment: loop contains only the first x posts. Not all of them.